# Find ONLY Capital Letters in word through IN SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to do this in SQL Server

I have data such as

```
Belo Horizonte , MG - Brazil
São Paulo , SP - Brazil
Barueri , SP - Brazil
Ferraz de Vasconcelos , SP - Brazil
```

I need to select two letter word as that matches the pattern

```
Space Letter Letter
```

I have tried this

```
SUBSTRING(ADDRESS_BLOCK,PatIndex('% [A-Z][A-Z] %',ADDRESS_BLOCK),3)
```

But I need to consider only capital letters for this (i.e) output has to be

```
MG SP SP SP
```

And not include `de` as found in the last line of the example `Ferraz de Vasconcelos , SP - Brazil`

Clear view on the problem

Eg: vaishnava st northwind GH -- Result has to be GH

```
 somersert PM vailash hj  --Result has to be PM
```

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience caused..

Comment: What collation sequence is the column using?

Comment: collation we use the genereic- Its not case sensitive (English)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:  You need to both collate the column AND specify the capital letters.  The regular expression [A-Z] is not case sensitive, even if you specify a collation sequence.

```
SELECT    SUBSTRING(
            ADDRESS_BLOCK
            , PatIndex(    
                N'% [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ] %'
                , ADDRESS_BLOCK COLLATE sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as
                )
            , 3
            ) 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 'Belo Horizonte , MG - Brazil' ADDRESS_BLOCK
        UNION
        SELECT 'São Paulo , SP - Brazil' 
        UNION
        SELECT 'Barueri , SP - Brazil' 
        UNION
        SELECT 'Ferraz de Vasconcelos , SP - Brazil' 
    ) n
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it... or a variation thereof to suit your needs.
In this case it'll pick out the first pair of of uppercase letters.

```
with dataset as 
(
    select 'Belo Horizonte , MG - Brazil' as val union all
    select 'São Paulo , SP - Brazil' as val union all 
    select 'Ferraz de Vasconcelos , SP - Brazil'  
)
select Substring(val ,PatIndex('%[A-Z][A-Z] %' COLLATE LATIN1_gENERAL_BIN,val),3)
from dataset
```

Comment: Whoops David Beat Me to It. :)

Answer (score 0):

Select 2 leters after comma:

```
select substring(columnname, charindex(',', columnname) + 2, 2)
from tablename
```

or using `-`:

```
select substring(columnname, charindex('-', columnname) - 3, 2)
from tablename
```

---

Final, not elegant, solution:

```
SUBSTRING(ADDRESS_BLOCK,PatIndex('% [ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQWXYZ][ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQWXYZ] %',ADDRESS_BLOCK),3)
```

It selects two uppercase letters.

Comment: i have given a example but all the values will not have ,

Comment: @ArunKumar do they have the `-` afterwords?

Comment: Thanks af your answers suits for this  but not for all my data bcoz sometimes it might not have the last word(-brazil) and some times it will not contan , also

Comment: @ArunKumar what about now? :)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, the above solution dosent select two upper case it selects the first two letters

Comment: @ArunKumar humm wicked, this `patindex` is really bad.. :P

Answer (score 0):

Could you just try this:

```
SUBSTRING([ADDRESS_BLOCK],PatIndex('%, [A-Z][A-Z] -%',[ADDRESS_BLOCK])+2,2)
```

[Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0266a/1/0)

Comment: This doesnt not work in this case                                     Av. Brig. Faria Lima,1355 4º andar São Paulo, SP 01452-002 Brazil

Comment: Will there always be a `[COMMA]` and `[SPACE]` before the two characters? Is it from user input or are you generating the values?

Comment: The case is 1) Always there is a space between two charaters but        comma cannot be assured as it might or might not contain comma

Answer (score -1):

Collation matters. You need to add `Collate` to your query, such as:

```
Select * from table where exists (Select SUBSTRING(ADDRESS_BLOCK,PatIndex('% [A-Z][A-Z] %',ADDRESS_BLOCK),3) from table)
COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS_KS_WS ASC;
```

You may need a difference collation - your current one is clearly case insensitive. You can find you current collation, and replace `Latin1_General_CS_AS_KS_WS` with the one you need, replacing the `CI` with `CS`, to get the case senstive version of your current collation.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx