# SQL Select only the words that are in Capital

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have for example an a column that starts with string values in capital letters and then continues in lower case:

```
THIS SENTENCE IS IN UPPERCASE and this in lower case
```

Is there any way to select the substring that contains uppercase letters?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033577/how-to-find-only-capital-letters-in-word-through-in-sql-server-query

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want to return the longest substring that only consists of uppercase letters? Or the longest leading substring that only consists of uppercase letters? Or filter out all lowercase characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @searchtext VARCHAR(100) = 'THIS SENTENCE IS IN UPPERCASE and this in lower case'
DECLARE @i INT = 1, @l INT = LEN(@searchtext)

WHILE (@i <= @l AND 1 = CHARINDEX(UPPER(LEFT(@searchtext,@i)),@searchtext COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS))
BEGIN
    SET @i = @i+1
END

SELECT RTRIM(LEFT(@searchtext, @i-1))
```

I can't get it to work with PATINDEX btw., no matter where I put the collation info.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @string = 'THIS SENTENCE IS IN UPPERCASE and this in lower case'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@string
                    ,PATINDEX('%[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]%',@string COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)
                    , PATINDEX('%[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]%',@string COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)-1)
```

[Reference link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7c31dff6-195e-4141-8bd5-0cf79cc2f499/problem-with-patindex-function-for-casesensitive-information)

Comment: Good catch. It didn't work for me with "[a-z]". But since the Upper case is always at the beginning you can get away with just "SELECT RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@string, 1, PATINDEX('%[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]%',@string COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)-1))". Oh and you need to handle the corner case without small characters...

Answer (score 0):

The above solution account for only words for one sentence in upper case followed by lower case words.

Jeff Moden et al have written a string spliter using a tally table.

I copied this function and installed it in my database.

The cte_Split_On_Spaces divides out all words.  Does not account for punctuation.

Then, the strings are collated to case sensitive, accent sensitive words.  If the upper case matches the normal word, it is in upper case.

This solution finds all upper case words in a string and list them by order.

You can easily put it back into a string.

Sincerely

John Miner
The Crafty Dba
www.craftydba.com

[image]

--

### -- Use splitter on paragraph, select upper case words

-- http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up

;
with
cte_Split_On_Spaces
as
(
select 
  * 
from 
  [dbo].[DelimitedSplitN4K] ('THIS SENTENCE IS IN UPPERCASE and this in lower case', ' ')
)
select 
    s.ItemNumber,
    s.Item 
from 
    cte_Split_On_Spaces s 
where 
   s.Item COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS = UPPER(s.Item COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS)