# How to get only Capital letters from given value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table it contains ID, Description and code columns. I need to fill code column using description column. Sample Description is "Investigations and Remedial Measures" so my code should be "IRM".

Note: Is there any words like "and/for/to/in" avoid it

Comment: Extract all capital letters or extract first letter of every word (with the given exceptions)?

Comment: Not sure on your DBMS.  For SQL Server: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033577/how-to-find-only-capital-letters-in-word-through-in-sql-server-query

Comment: Split  string into character and check their unicode value( for capital letter unicode is lie between 65  to 90.)

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server, 
Extract all capital letters of every word

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find ONLY Capital Letters in word through IN SQL Server query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033577/how-to-find-only-capital-letters-in-word-through-in-sql-server-query)

Comment: I used this one 
 with dataset as 
(
select 'Belo Horizonte Orange' as val union all
select 'São Paulo Lala' as val union all 
select 'Ferraz de Vasconcelos Toranto'  
)
select Substring(val ,PatIndex('%[A-Z][A-Z] %' COLLATE LATIN1_gENERAL_BIN,val),3)
from dataset

I got 
Be
Sã
Fe
But I need
1. BHO
2. SPL
3. SVT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code may help you..

```
 declare @input as varchar(1000) -- Choose the appropriate size
  declare @output as varchar(1000) -- Choose the appropriate size

 select @input = 'Investigations and Remedial Measures', @output = ''

 declare @i int

select @i = 0

while @i < len(@input)
begin
select @i = @i + 1

select @output = @output +  case when  unicode(substring(@input, @i, 1))between 65 
   and 90 then substring(@input, @i, 1)  else '' end

end

SELECT @output
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would do this with an inline table-valued function

On SQL Server 2017 or better, or Azure SQL Database:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.ExtractUpperCase(@s nvarchar(4000))
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  RETURN 
  (
    WITH s(s) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT s+1 FROM s WHERE s < LEN(@s))
    SELECT TOP (3) value = STRING_AGG(SUBSTRING(@s,s,1),'') 
      WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY s.s) 
      FROM s WHERE ASCII(SUBSTRING(@s,s,1)) BETWEEN 65 AND 90
  );
GO
```

On SQL Server 2016 or older:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ExtractUpperCase(@s nvarchar(4000))
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  RETURN 
  (
    WITH s(s) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT s+1 FROM s WHERE s < LEN(@s))
    SELECT value = (SELECT TOP (3) v = SUBSTRING(@s,s,1) FROM s
      WHERE ASCII(SUBSTRING(@s,s,1)) BETWEEN 65 AND 90 
      ORDER BY s.s FOR XML PATH(''), 
      TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]',N'nvarchar(4000)')
  );
GO
```

In either case:

```
CREATE TABLE #x(id int, name nvarchar(4000));

INSERT #x(id, name) VALUES
  (1, N'Belo Horizonte Orange'),
  (2, N'São Paulo Lala'),
  (3, N'Ferraz de Vasconcelos Toranto');

SELECT id, f.value FROM #x AS x
  CROSS APPLY dbo.ExtractUpperCase(x.name) AS f
  ORDER BY id OPTION (MAXRECURSION 4000);
```

Results:

```
id     name
----   ----
1      BHO
2      SPL
3      SVT
```

The `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 4000)` is only necessary if your strings can be longer than 100 characters.