# Select String based on capital words

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to do something similiar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11058109/1383668. The difference is I have entire words that are capital and dynamic. This is the data

```
THE box is on the desk by the door WILLIAM ran ten miles in world record time DO you know the way to San Jose APPLES to apples is a baking term that is used often when making a pie
```

This is how it should look when I run it.

```
THE box is on the desk by the door 
WILLIAM ran ten miles in world record time 
DO you know the way to San Jose 
APPLES to apples is a baking term that is used often when making a pie
```

Comment: What about `I` or `SAN JOSE`?

Comment: Does one string become multiple records or one string with CRLFs ?

Comment: @AaronBertrand the whole word must be capitalized (THE, DO, APPLES etc). So it would not not be broken up with the words San Jose

Comment: @JohnCappelletti yes multiple records

Comment: I'm trying to help you identify edge cases that aren't in the data you've shown but might be in the data where you apply a solution. If a one-letter, upper-case word like `I` appears in the data, should that be pushed to the next line? If two consecutive upper-case words like `SAN JOSE` appear in the data, does `SAN JOSE` appear together on the next line, or does `SAN` appear on the next line and `JOSE` on the line after that?

Comment: @Aaron Looking over the data, I would say that the words would have to be two or more consecutive letters. So San Jose spelled like this would not apply nor would the letter I.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I run my data again there are some records that have two words all capitals like with your example SAN JOSE. So yes SAN JOSE would be on one line and not split.

Answer (score 2):

With the aid of a split/parse function

To be clear, I added a little bit of logic to trap single letter capital words such as **I**.   `len(RetVal)>1`

To Aaron's point, double words may require a lead/lag trap.

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = 'THE box is on the desk by the door WILLIAM ran ten miles in world record time DO you know the way to San Jose APPLES to apples is a baking term that is used often when making a pie'

;with cte as (
Select *
      ,grp = sum(case when len(RetVal)>1 and upper(RetVal)=RetVal COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS then 1 else 0 end) over (order by RetSeq)
 From  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](@S,' ')
)
Select RN = Grp
      ,NewValue = Stuff((Select ' ' +RetVal From cte Where Grp=A.Grp Order By RetSeq For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
 From  cte A
 Group By Grp
```

**Returns**

```
RN  NewValue
1   THE box is on the desk by the door
2   WILLIAM ran ten miles in world record time
3   DO you know the way to San Jose
4   APPLES to apples is a baking term that is used often when making a pie
```

**The TVF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by 1/0)
          ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.'))) as A(x)
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
```

> **EDIT - If you don't want to add the Table-Valued Function**

```
;with cte as (
Select *
      ,grp = sum(case when len(RetVal)>1 and upper(RetVal)=RetVal COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS then 1 else 0 end) over (order by RetSeq)
 From  (
       Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by 1/0)
              ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
        From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@S,' ','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.'))) as A(x)
        Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
       ) A
)
Select RN = Grp
      ,NewValue = Stuff((Select ' ' +RetVal From cte Where Grp=A.Grp Order By RetSeq For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
 From  cte A
 Group By Grp
```