# Return word with the capital letter from string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column like:

```
column1
-------------
this is a New world
this is a kind Person
this is a good Idea
```

How to get:

```
column1
------------------
New
Person
Idea
```

Assume there is only one word with the capital letter per string.

Comment: some function like UPPER, but I don't need to upper the string.

Comment: When I google it the first result is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033577/how-to-find-only-capital-letters-in-word-through-in-sql-server-query which appears to answer the question?

Comment: this answer shows returning 3 letters, How to return the entire word?

Comment: Find the next space or end of string and use that to set the length of sub-string.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? If it is 2016 or higher check out the [STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [ASCII()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ascii-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) functions. We want to help, but we want you to put forth some effort. And if you have, show it to us. As it is, it feels like you want us to do your homework for you.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need `PATINDEX` (to find any of the capital letters within the string), `CHARINDEX` (to find the position of space after the capital letter or end of the string) and `SUBSTRING` (to get the part of the whole string).

try the following:

```
declare @tab table (column1 varchar(100))
insert into @tab select 'this is a New world'
insert into @tab select 'this is a kind Person'
insert into @tab select 'this is a good Idea'

select * from @tab

select substring(column1, PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', column1 COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN)
                , case when CHARINDEX(' ', substring(column1, PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', column1 COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN), len(column1)), 1) = 0
                        then len(column1) else CHARINDEX(' ', substring(column1, PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%', column1 COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN), len(column1)), 1)-1 end) as column1
from @tab
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `STRING_SPLIT` to separate each word into a database row, e.g.:

```
value
-----
this
is
a
New
world
...
Person
```

Then you can use `COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS` to do a case sensitive string comparison and isolate the rows where the first character is upper case:

```
Select value
FROM tbl
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(column1, ' ') -- the 'value' column comes from this
WHERE SUBSTRING(value, 1, 1) = UPPER(SUBSTRING(value, 1, 1)) -- compare 1st character
COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS -- makes the string comparison case-sensitive
```

Returns:

```
value
New
Person
Idea
```

[Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6c51cd/3)

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw my hat in the ring with a slight variation.

```
create table MyTable
(
id int,
column1 varchar(100)
)

insert into MyTable (id, column1) values 
(1, 'this is a New world'),
(2, 'this is a kind Person'), 
(3, 'this is a good Idea')

select value
from MyTable
cross apply string_split(column1, ' ')
where ascii(left(value, 1)) between 65 and 90 -- ASCII value range of upper case letters
```

Here is the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=79e90dab6a3ce6c51a2334ca2308c43a).